# Get data using annotate with joining 3 tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 3 tables:-

```
    class Organization(models.Model):
       id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       name = models.CharField()
       .....
       #some more field
       .....



    class Billing(models.Model):
         id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
         amount = models.IntegerField()
         .....
         #some more field
         ....

.
   class Payment(models.Model):
       id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       billing = models.ForeignKey(Billing)
       organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
       paymentDate = models.DateTimeField()
       .....
       #some more field
       ....
```

Whenever payment has done by `organization` it creates a new entry for `payment` table every time and updates the `billing` amount. And there are multiple billing objects are available billing table. So I am calculating the sum of amount and latest payment done for the particular organization using annotate.

I have stuck to find the `latest payment date` for the organization in using annotate query.

```
billing.objects.filter(
            orgId_id__in = organizationIdList,
            isCancel=0,
            billTime__range=(startDate, endDate)
        ).values('orgId_id').annotate(
            total_amount = Sum('amount'),
            lastest_payment_time = "HERE I AM STUCK",
        )
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) and [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
 latest_payment = Payment.objects.filter(organization=OuterRef('organization')).order_by("-paymentDate")
 Billing.objects.filter(organization__id__in=organizationIdList).values('organization__id').annotate(total_amount=SUM('amount'), latest_payment=Subquery(latest_payment.values('paymentDate')[:1]))
```

For this solution you will need at least **Django 1.11**.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: happy to help :)